# dynamic google-service.json after apk is generated

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native

I have an app that sync data with my API.
I want this app have a dynamic "google-service.json", I want to pass the google-service.json after the app.APK is ready and the app is installed on the device through my API. 
Is possible ? 
I did a generic "google-service.json" that change the values when I send data from my API to the installed app on the device but the Firebase connection is not working.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're asking isn't possible.  The values from google-services.json are read at build time and added to your APK.  There's no way to go back and changes those values later.

If you want to initialize Firebase based on values that can only be known when the app is launched, then you should NOT apply the google-sevices plugin in build.gradle, and instead call [FirebaseApp.initializeApp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp) manually and pass the correct values that you see in google-services.json.

Read:

- https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/take-control-of-your-firebase-init-on.html
- https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

Comment: Doug when you answered me and I did this on my app and thats ok, the only think that I can't do is push notifications (Firebase Cloud Message) for Android, because of the SenderID. There is some Firebase function that I can receive the SenderID ? Just to explain, the app opens then I manually pass the Firebase values and I connect to Firebase but I don't have the SenderID.

Comment: Please post a new question describing what you're trying to accomplish.