# Is it possible to fill out google-service.json later after application build as apk

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

Is it possible to fill out google-service.json keys later after application build as apk file where users fill it from text field inside the application? I want the users able to connect to spesific firebase connection without needed to get my source code and configure it in android studio first.

I do found similar question but its hard to understand from my level of knowledge or satisfy my question: [dynamic google-service.json after apk is generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59346582/dynamic-google-service-json-after-apk-is-generated)

Comment: No. You'll need to call `FirebaseApp.initializeApp()` with the contents you'd find in your dynamic google-services.json OR resort to a few flavors of the app that contain different google-services.json files.

Comment: @Shark So, is it still posible if I dont using google-service.json and instead using FirebaseApp.initializeApp() where the values is from text input? Im still new to firebase and programming in general, so sorry if im so dumb about this. I hardly find any tutorial that I wanted

Comment: Yes, thats exactly it. If you have some file in `assets/` which you read, you could offer the user a choice of which firebase to connect to from within the app.